# Use useVirtualList from VueUse to render HeadlessUI's Listbox component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, headless-ui

I want to use [VueUse's virtual scroller](https://vueuse.org/core/usevirtuallist/) composable to render the [HeadlessUI's listbox](https://headlessui.dev/vue/listbox) content.

This is what I tried:

```html
<Listbox v-model="selectedIcon">
  <div class="relative mt-1">
    <ListboxButton class="bg-white rounded-lg cursor-default shadow-md text-left w-full py-2 pr-10 pl-3 relative sm:text-sm focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 focus-visible:ring-offset-2">
      <span class="block truncate">test</span>
      <span class="flex pr-2 inset-y-0 right-0 absolute items-center pointer-events-none">
        <SelectorIcon class="h-5 text-gray-400 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
      </span>
    </ListboxButton>

    <ListboxOptions v-bind="containerProps" class="bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg ring-black mt-1 text-base w-full max-h-60 h-full py-1 ring-1 ring-opacity-5 absolute overflow-auto sm:text-sm focus:outline-none">
      <div v-bind="wrapperProps">
        <ListboxOption v-slot="{ active, selected }" v-for="icon in list" :key="icon.data.name" :value="icon">
          <li>
            <span>{{ icon.data.name }}</span>
          </li>
        </ListboxOption>
      </div>
    </ListboxOptions>
  </div>
</Listbox>
```

And this is the virtual scroller composable:

```js
const { list, containerProps, wrapperProps } = useVirtualList(icons, { itemHeight: 40 })
```

The problem is that when I try to open the listbox, I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at watch.immediate (index.mjs:1322)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6737)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6746)
    at Array.job (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7154)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6938)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6983)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6991)
```

I also get this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback 
  at <ApplicationIconSelector key=0 > 
  at <Anonymous as="template" enter="ease-out duration-300" enter-from="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"  ... > 
  at <ForcePortalRoot force=false > 
  at <PortalGroup target= <div class=​"fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" id=​"headlessui-dialog-4" role=​"dialog" aria-modal=​"true" aria-labelledby=​"headlessui-dialog-title-8">​…​</div>​<div class=​"flex min-h-screen text-center px-4 pt-4 pb-20 items-end justify-center sm:​p-0 sm:​block">​<div id=​"headlessui-dialog-overlay-6" aria-hidden=​"true" class=​"bg-gray-975 bg-opacity-85 inset-0 transition-opacity fixed">​</div>​<!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. --><span class=​"hidden sm:​h-screen sm:​inline-block sm:​align-middle" aria-hidden=​"true">​&ZeroWidthSpace;​</span>​<div class=​"rounded-lg shadow-xl text-left transform transition-all text-gray-850 inline-block align-bottom sm:​max-w-lg sm:​my-8 sm:​w-full sm:​align-middle dark:​text-gray-200">​<div class=​"rounded-t-lg bg-gray-25 px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:​p-6 sm:​pb-4 dark:​bg-gray-925">​…​</div>​<div class=​"bg-gray-75 py-3 px-3 sm:​flex sm:​flex-row-reverse dark:​bg-gray-900">​…​</div>​flex<button class=​"flex-y-center justify-center p-2 px-3 font-medium text-sm transition duration-75 select-none cursor-pointer focus:​outline-none rounded-md bg-gray-75 text-gray-850 hover:​bg-gray-100 active:​bg-gray-175 dark:​text-gray-250 dark:​bg-gray-875 dark:​hover:​bg-gray-850 dark:​active:​bg-gray-825 w-full">​…​</button>​flex</div>​</div>​</div>​</div>​ > 
  at <Portal> 
  at <ForcePortalRoot force=true > 
  at <Dialog as="div" class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" ref="el"  ... > 
  at <Anonymous onBeforeEnter=fn<onBeforeEnter> onAfterEnter=fn<onAfterEnter> onBeforeLeave=fn<onBeforeLeave>  ... > 
  at <Anonymous as="template" show=true data=null > 
  at <AddEditApplication modelValue=true onUpdate:modelValue=fn data=null > 
  at <Index onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {__v_skip: true} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Looks like it is attempting to bind itself to something other than a native DOM element. In the example on the VueUse site they show native DOM elements with the `v-bind` directive. However, your code uses `v-bind` on non-native DOM elements, you have it on a VNode (the ListBox component).

Even looking at the source code you can see that the binding of `containerProps` expects an `HTMLElement`.

```
const containerRef: Ref = ref<HTMLElement | null>()
```

I've not used HeadlessUI before, but looking at the source code for the `ListBoxOptions` component it appears that it does not render any elements outside of what is passed into its default slot; aka your `<div v-bind="wrapperProps">`. Is your list of classes even rendering on anything? Hard to tell how your code is running without an example.

I recommend creating another `div`, nested inside of `ListBoxOptions`, that wraps the `<div v-bind="wrapperProps">` element. On this new `div` move the `v-bind="containerProps"` from the `ListBoxOptions` onto it; see below.

```
<ListboxOptions>
  <div v-bind="containerProps" class="bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg ring-black mt-1 text-base w-full max-h-60 h-full py-1 ring-1 ring-opacity-5 absolute overflow-auto sm:text-sm focus:outline-none">
    <div v-bind="wrapperProps">
      <ListboxOption v-slot="{ active, selected }" v-for="icon in list" :key="icon.data.name" :value="icon">
        <li>
          <span>{{ icon.data.name }}</span>
        </li>
      </ListboxOption>
    </div>
  </div>
</ListboxOptions>
```

I think that may fix your issue.